# Не могу слить 2 массива в один

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, объединение

никак не могу объединить 2 массива в 1, массивы формируются из базы mysql, array_merge не помог

Мне нужен 1 массив, чтоб полностью слить, заранее всем спасибо, очень рассчитываю на вашу помощь

Мой код php Модели (он формирует и объединяет массивы)

```
public function get_Product_from_Att($att_id, $att_value_id) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `import_attribute_values` WHERE `id`= '$att_value_id'");
    $res = $query->row;

$ImportAttValue = trim($res['idimport']);


$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `os_product_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = '$att_id' and `text` = '$ImportAttValue'");
$product_ids = $query->rows;


foreach ($product_ids as $product_id){

  $product_id = $product_id['product_id'];

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `os_product` WHERE `product_id` = '$product_id'");
    $row1=$query->rows;

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `os_product_description` WHERE `product_id` = '$product_id'");
    $row2 = $query->rows;   

$result = array_merge($row1, $row2);    


}

return $result;     

    }
```

На выходе получаются 2 массива, но нужен один

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 7
            [model] => 2018
            [sku] => 
            [upc] => 659737
            [ean] => 84х108/32
            [jan] => твердый
            [isbn] => 978-5-17-109810-0, 978-0-000-00000-2, 978-0-000-00000-2
            [mpn] => 320
            [location] => 
            [quantity] => 100
            [stock_status_id] => 7
            [image] => catalog/import_files/dir_pic/659737.jpg
            [manufacturer_id] => 4
            [shipping] => 1
            [options_buy] => 0
            [price] => 300.0000
            [points] => 0
            [tax_class_id] => 0
            [date_available] => 0000-00-00
            [weight] => 0.00
            [weight_class_id] => 1
            [length] => 0.00
            [width] => 0.00
            [height] => 0.00
            [length_class_id] => 1
            [subtract] => 1
            [minimum] => 1
            [sort_order] => 1
            [status] => 1
            [viewed] => 5
            [date_added] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [date_modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        )

`[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 7
        [language_id] => 1
        [name] => Витя Малеев в школе и дома. Повесть и рассказы
        [description] => &lt;p&gt;В книгу классика детской литературы Н.Н. Носова «Витя Малеев в школе и дома. Повесть и рассказы» вошла повесть о Вите Малееве и рассказы. Герои Носова весёлые и непосредственные. Они умеют дружить и справляться со своими недостатками. В 1952 году Н.Н. Носов за повесть «Витя Малеев в школе и дома» получил Сталинскую премию. В 1954 году по повести был снят фильм «Два друга». Иллюстрации в книге народного художника СССР В.Н. Горяева. Для младшего школьного возраста.&lt;/p&gt;
        [short_description] => 
        [tag] => 
        [meta_title] => Носов Николай Николаевич - Витя Малеев в школе и дома. Повесть и рассказы - 978-5-17-109810-0, 978-0-000-00000-2, 978-0-000-00000-2
        [meta_h1] => Витя Малеев в школе и дома. Повесть и рассказы
        [meta_description] => Продажа книг для взрослых и детей. Витя Малеев в школе и дома. Повесть и рассказы выгодно. Огромный выбор по самым различным тематикам
        [meta_keyword] => Витя Малеев в школе и дома. Повесть и рассказы, купить, выгодно, в магазине, онлайн
    )`

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может все-таки выбрать все сразу одним запросом ?

```
public function get_Product_from_Att($att_id, $att_value_id) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `import_attribute_values` WHERE `id`= '$att_value_id'");
    $res = $query->row;

$ImportAttValue = trim($res['idimport']);


$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `os_product_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = '$att_id' and `text` = '$ImportAttValue'");
$product_ids = $query->rows;


foreach ($product_ids as $product_id){

  $product_id = $product_id['product_id'];

    $query = $this->db->query("
SELECT p.*, pd.* FROM `os_product` `p` LEFT JOIN `os_product_description` `pd` ON p.product_id = pd.product_id WHERE p.product_id = '$product_id'
");
    $row=$query->rows;

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($row); die; 


}

return $result;     

    }
```

Comment: ну так и написали бы все действительно одним запросом, ато вдруг в $product_ids = $query->rows; будет 100 товаров. 100 раз мускуль дергать?
Тогда уж в "WHERE p.product_id" добавить "IN ()" и туда закинуть все id продуктов.

Comment: @kevin Предложите свой вариант, если у вас есть идея лучше, и в описании укажите преимущества вашего варианта.

Comment: я написал ответ на конкретный вопрос

Comment: Огромное человеческое спасибо Вам madfan41k

Comment: ы ) за что мне минус поставили то ?

Comment: Потому что запрос в цикле...

Answer (score -1):

ну или более оптимизированный вариант

```
public function get_Product_from_Att($att_id, $att_value_id) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `import_attribute_values` WHERE `id`= '$att_value_id'");
    $res = $query->row;

    $ImportAttValue = trim($res['idimport']);


    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `os_product_attribute` WHERE `attribute_id` = '$att_id' and `text` = '$ImportAttValue'");

    $product_ids = $query->rows;

    $prodIds = '';
    foreach ($product_ids as $pid) {
        $prodIds .= $pid['product_id'] . ', ';
    }

    $res = [];

    if ($prodIds != '') {

        $prodIds = substr($prodIds, 0, -2);

        $query = $this->db->query( "SELECT p.*, pd.* FROM `os_product` `p` LEFT JOIN `os_product_description` `pd` ON p.product_id = pd.product_id WHERE p.product_id IN('{$prodIds}')" );

        $res = $query->rows;
    }

    return $res;     
}
```

т.е. Если $prodIds пуст, то вернется пустой массив и база дергаться вообще не будет.

Comment: $prodIds = implode(', ', $product_ids); и как туда айдишники попадут ? )))

Comment: пардон, не заметил что айдишники возвращаются в ассоциативном массиве с первого запроса